# JUJU ERROR failed to bootstrap environment: subprocess encountered error code 1

Tags: juju, maas

I have configured a MAAS Server (on VM) with two nodes. When both the nodes are PXE booted & their status on MAAS Web interface becomes "Ready", I give the command "juju bootstrap -e maas". Then, after sometime, the bootstrapping process halts giving following error at the end:

```
Attempt 5 to download tools from https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.24.6-trusty-i386.tgz...
curl: (7) Failed to connect to streams.canonical.com port 443: Connection timed out
tools from https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.24.6-trusty-i386.tgz downloaded: HTTP 000; time 126.334s; size 0 bytes; speed 0.000 bytes/s sha256sum: /var/lib/juju/tools/1.24.6-trusty-i386/tools.tar.gz: No such file or directory
ERROR failed to bootstrap environment: subprocess encountered error code 1
```

Please suggest the solution to the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a proxy to reach the internet? If yes, configure it in your juju environment. Add these lines accordingly:

```
http-proxy: http://ip:port
https-proxy: http://ip:port
no-proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1,somethingelse
```

Comment: No i do not need the proxy. Actually i am able to download the file "juju-1.24.6-trusty-i386.tgz" using the following command:

Comment: "wget https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.24.6-trusty-i386.tgz"

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I found out that juju's lxd subnet can't access the internet, so `apt-get update` and `upgrade`were "completing" however I wasn't able to see the commands themselves. They will say completed even if `apt-get` update fails all links. `apt-get upgrade` will just say everything's ok and nothing more to install, then it'll hang on installing cURL and stuff because while you might have internet access, your subnet doesn't.

This [Lauchpad answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/juju/+question/262760) really helped me and I think I might've solved that issue for myself. I'm 95% sure that it's your subnet not having access to the internet (because remember that lxd creates a subnet for you. 10.x.x.x) but I wasn't able to get to the GUI or ssh into any of those subnet machines which is what tipped me off. Check it out. Run the bootstrap command with `--debug` and see what happens. For me it just tells me it can't connect to any API adresses, which obviously means no internet on the slave machines.